# MySQL Workbench 8.0 WbAdmin.testInstanceSettingByName

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Has this issue been addressed?  I have complete access with new user after creation. But when I go through configure local management on workbench, it locates my config file but throws the same error:
Operation failed: error calling Python module function WbAdmin.testInstanceSettingByName.  I would like to know what is happening and resolve it rather than going backwards to a previous release.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I had also the same error come up but I didn't get any obstacle to my connection.

This happens because of:

On the Admin screen, the server configuration option Key buffer, was located under the General tab, rather than the MyISAM Parameters tab, even though it was a MyISAM-only option.

In the configuration editor in the Admin tab, the lists for displaying units, such as for the Sort buffer size option, did not show 'G', which represents Gigabytes. This bug was fixed in 5.2.10.

It was subsequently decided to standardize all units around uppercase characters. In particular the 'k' was changed to 'K'. This change was made in version 5.2.13.

In the SQL Editor, the database explorer of the Schemata palette in the side panel did not work correctly. Incorrect behavior included random collapsing of expanded databases and occasional crashing.

When using the data modeler, MySQL Workbench extended vertically to the maximum size of the screen, overlapping the dock, and thereby making it impossible to use.

In the Manage Server Instances dialog, if the Server Instances list pane was empty, then on creating a new Server Instance, it was not possible to change the instance's name. The instance had to be created, the dialog closed. On reopening the dialog, the instance could be renamed.

The Generate Catalog Diff Report feature did not permit the comparison of imported scripts because selecting the radio button for this option had no effect.

If a collation was changed for a table in the Table Editor, there was no facility to then set this back to the schema default.

A new entry has been now been added to the collation selection list: Schema Default.

When a model containing stored routines was forward engineered to a script, the script contained an erroneous additional delimiter after each stored routine. This resulted in a “No query specified” error when an attempt was made to run the script on a server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue,
the problem was that there was some weird characters in **my.ini** file that causes the decode error.[Bug Report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=103332&thanks=3)

**Solution is**

1. Open my.ini File
2. Delete all the comments above server-id [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQf07.png)
3. Save & Restart Workbench

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered this issue for mysql installed in Windows. So I had re-run **mysql-installer-web-community-8.0.30.0** and reconfigured the MySQL Server, WorkBench which resolved the above issue